# mixing my jquery with an onclick event also tied to a SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The issue is that no post back occurs. I noticed that if I returned true this would not be the be case .. however there were non-deterministic results so I am at a loss.
Any help appreciated!

```
          <DropDownList ID="ddlS1" runat="server" onclick = "checkHighDegreeCompliance(this, 1);" SelectedIndexChanged = "ddlS1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
```

Here is the markup on the actual page after loading

```
<select name="rptrSection1$ctl00$rptrSection2$ctl00$ddlS2" class="DDLSelector2 SDropDown IsNormal" id="rptrSection1_ctl00_rptrSection2_ctl00_ddlS2" style="width: 200px;" onchange="checkHighDegreeCompliance(this, 2);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'rptrSection1$ctl00$rptrSection2$ctl00$ddlS2\',\'\')', 0)">
```

Here is the javascript

```
function checkHighDegreeCompliance(obj, sectionNum)
{
var parDdl = $(obj);
var parCompLev = parDdl.attr('selectedIndex');
var pnlDiv = parDdl.parents('.Section');
var ddls = pnlDiv.find('.DDLSelector' + (sectionNum + 1));
ddls.each(function ()
{
    var childDDL = $(this);
    var childComLev = childDDL.attr('selectedIndex');
    if (childComLev > parCompLev)
    {
        parDdl.attr('selectedIndex', childComLev);
    }
    if (sectionNum < 4)
    {
        checkHighDegreeCompliance(childDDL, ++sectionNum);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish by the code given. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: I have a nested repeater structure.  the template of every repeater except the 4th one looks like so
<Template> <DDL> <Repeater> </Template> each inner repeater is the same except that the 4th just has DDLs. The idea is that there is a an ability to select a value from the DDL then it will recursively check all the inner repeaters and associated DDLs to ensure that the new selected top level value doesn't conflict with inner block values ... i.e, a top level DDL value cannot be lower than an inner block element. The same is true inversely, the highest degree elem propagates up the block struct

Comment: But the real issue is that I cannot get a post back to occur when I bind to the onchange event. Is there another approach to ensuring the changeHighDegreeComliance() method is fired (preferably BEFORE the server-side event is finished).

Answer (score 0):

try with `return` keyword before the `onclick` event

```
 <DropDownList ID="ddlS1" runat="server" onclick = "return checkHighDegreeCompliance(this, 1);" SelectedIndexChanged = "ddlS1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
```

Let me know if it not worked.